# Nonlinear regression in R with multiple categorical dependent variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, non-linear-regression

I have to perform a nonlinear multiple regression with data that looks like the following:

```
ID    Customer   Country   Industry      Machine-type    Service hours**
1     A          China     mass          A1              120
2     B          Europe    customized    A2              400
3     C          US        mass          A1               60
4     D          Rus       mass          A3              250
5     A          China     mass          A2              480
6     B          Europe    customized    A1              300
7     C          US        mass          A4              250
8     D          Rus       customized    A2              260
9     A          China     Customized    A2              310
10    B          Europe    mass          A1              110
11    C          US        Customized    A4               40
12    D          Rus       customized    A2              80
```

**Dependent variable:** Service hours
**Independent variables:** Customer, Country, Industry, Machine type

I did a linear regression, but because the assumption of linearity does not hold I have to perform a **nonlinear regression.**

I know nonlinear regression can be done with the nls function. How do I **add the categorical variables to the nonlinear regression** so that I get the **statistical summary** in R?

Column names after adding dummies: [table with dummies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCT5L.jpg)

```
ID  Customer.a  Customer.b  Customer.c  Customer.d  Country.China   Country.Europe  Country.Rus Country.US  Industry.customized industry.Customized Industry.mass   Machine type.A1 Machine type.A2 Machine type.A3 Service hours
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 120 
2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 400 
3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 60 
4 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 250 
5 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 480 
6 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 300 
7 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 250 
8 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 260 
9 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 210 
10 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 110 
11 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 40 
12 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 80
```

Comment: Not sure if the function you are using can take factor variables or you may need to create dummy variables. Have a look at the `dummies` package

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer so quick! Yes, I used the dummies package. So now I have multiple dummies, but how can I put those dummies into a nonlinear function in which the statistical summary results?

Comment: > datadum <- dummy.data.frame(Map1, sep = ".")
> names(datadum)
 [1] "ID"                  "Customer.a"          "Customer.b"         
 [4] "Customer.c"          "Customer.d"          "Country.China"      
 [7] "Country.Europe"      "Country.Rus"         "Country.US"         
[10] "Industry.customized" "Industry.Customized" "Industry.mass"      
[13] "Machine type.A1"     "Machine type.A2"     "Machine type.A3"    
[16] "Service hours"

Comment: these are the dummies I get. I would like to add them to a nonlinear regression. Thank you in advance for helping me!

Comment: Can you update the data frame in the question please

Comment: I added the table, but I do not know how to make a nice table from it as the last one. Therefore I added a picture. Thankyou!

Comment: The data looks goods to go now. You should be able to fit a model.

Comment: model <- nls(datadum$`Service hours` ~ datadum$Customer.a + datadum$Customer.b + datadum$Customer.c + datadum$Customer.d 
             + datadum$Country.China + datadum$Country.Europe + datadum$Country.Rus + datadum$Country.US + datadum$Industry.customized
             + datadum$Industry.Customized + datadum$Industry.mass + datadum$`Machine type.A1` + datadum$`Machine type.A2` + datadum$`Machine type.A3`)

Comment: this is what I would have done with the lm function, but how does it work proper for the nls function?

Comment: Perform a `make.names()` on your dataset to remove the space between the response and use formula

`nls(Service.hours ~ . -ID, data = df)`

Comment: Note I assume you will also have to specify your algorithm and start parameter, above is just an example.

Comment: Ok! nice, that worked.

Comment: Excellent, I'll write out an answer :)

Comment: do I have to do something with the warning message? and how do I interpret these results? can I say something about the predicted value of the independent variables? output: > nls(Hours ~ . -ID, data = df)
Nonlinear regression model
  model: Hours ~ . - ID
   data: df
    . 
219.8 
 residual sum-of-squares: 204970

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.825e-16
Warning message:
In nls(Hours ~ . - ID, data = df) :
  No starting values specified for some parameters.
Initializing ‘.’ to '1.'.
Consider specifying 'start' or using a selfStart model

Comment: hm, you may need to specify your predictors in the formula. Usually the period is interpreted as 'all'. Not really sure what that start parameter is. In terms of interpretation of results, look at the coefficients attached to the predictors.

Comment: Ok, how do you know which algorithm and start parameter to use? My predictors are Customer, Country, Machine and Industry. How to add these predictors?

Comment: The default algorithm is a Gauss-Newton algorithm. I think you are after the `plinear` algorithm. When in doubt, refer to the documentation of that function. `?nls`

Comment: Thanks! Is this the way to add plinear? If I add plinear, I get the warning message of not having starting values: how do I solve this? > nls(Hours ~ . -ID, data = df, algorithm = "plinear", start = )
Error in nls(Hours ~ . - ID, data = df, algorithm = "plinear", start = ) : 
  no starting values specified

Comment: I also don't get the following output: 
Parameters:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle categorical predictors is dependent on the number of levels the predictor can hold.

For predictors such as gender which can only take 2 forms (male or female), you can simply represent them as a binary (1,0) variable.

For predictors with greater than 2 levels, we use 1-of-k dummy encoding where k is the number of levels the particular variable takes. See the [dummies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dummies/dummies.pdf) package for useful functions!

After this, you can fit the model using formula:

```
nls(Service.hours ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + predictorN, data = df)
```

Comment: If I use this nls function I get the following error:
> test2nls <- nls(Hours ~ ID + Customer.a + Customer.b
+                 + Customer.c + Customer.d + Country.China
+                 + Country.Europe + Country.Rus
+                 + Industry.customized + Industry.Customized
+                 + Industry.mass + Machine.A1 + Machine.A2
+                 + Machine.A3, data = df)
Error in getInitial.default(func, data, mCall = as.list(match.call(func,  : 
  no 'getInitial' method found for "function" objects